# Split a file into a list

Tags: python

This is what I have so far:

```
EX1 = open('ex1.txt')
EX1READ = EX1.read()
X1READ.splitlines(0)

['jk43:23 Marfield Lane:Plainview:NY:10023',
 'axe99:315 W. 115th Street, Apt. 11B:New      York:NY:10027',
 'jab44:23 Rivington Street, Apt. 3R:New York:NY:10002',
 'ap172:19 Boxer Rd.:New York:NY:10005',
 'jb23:115 Karas Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127',
 'jb29:119 Xylon Dr.:Jersey City:NJ:07127',
 'ak9:234 Main Street:Philadelphia:PA:08990']
```

I'd like to be able to just grab the userId from this list and print it alphabetized.  Any hints would be great.

Comment: I hope that isn't real user data...

Comment: The user ID is which part of the file, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
userIds = []

EX1 = open('ex1.txt')
X1READ = EX1.readlines()

for line in X1READ:
    useridname = line.split(" ")[0].split(":")[0];
    userid = line.split(" ")[0].split(":")[1]
    userIds.append([useridname, userid])
```

I'm sure there are more Pythonic ways to do this, but my method will return an list of lists, where each child list in the parent list is formatted like this:

```
["jk43", "23"]
```

So to get the first user id and id number, you'd do this:

```
firstUserId = userIds[0][0] + ": " + userIds[0][1]
```

Which would output

> > "jk43: 23"

To sort the list of IDs, you'd do something like this:

```
userIds = sorted(userIds, key = id: id[0])
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: To alphabetize, you can just write `userIds.sort()` at the end of the above solution.  It will sort by the first field, and if they are identical, by the second field.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
IDs=[]
with open('ex1.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        IDs.append(line.split(':')[0])

print sorted(IDs)
```

Prints:

```
['ak9', 'ap172', 'axe99', 'jab44', 'jb23', 'jb29', 'jk43']
```

If your user id's like `jk43:23` use `IDs.append(line.split(' ')[0])` and that prints:

```
['ak9:234', 'ap172:19', 'axe99:315', 'jab44:23', 'jb23:115', 'jb29:119', 'jk43:23']
```

If your user ids are the number only, use `IDs.append(int(line.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]))` which prints:

```
[19, 23, 23, 115, 119, 234, 315]
```

Comment: Setting `maxsplit` to 1 may prove more efficient if line is long, e.g. `IDs.append(line.split(':', 1)[0])`.

Comment: It is unclear what the user id is: `jk43:23` or just `jk43` for example. This is the former, not the latter. Extending to the later is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the part before the first ":" is the userID you could do it in a more pythonic way like that:

```
with open("ex1.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    userIDs = [l.split(":",1)[0] for l in lines]
    print "\n".join(sorted(userIDs))
```